# Remove "[ and ]" from csv file using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a row such as this

```
0,"['low', 'low', 'low']","['better', 'better', 'better', 'better', 'better', 'better']","['True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True']"
```

And I'd like to get rid of the "[ ] from teach of the line. Right now  I am separately running

> sed -i 's/\"//g' File.csv
>
> sed -i 's/\[/ /g' File.csv
>
> sed -i 's/\]//g'  File.csv

to get

```
0, 'low', 'low', 'low', 'better', 'better', 'better', 'better', 'better', 'better', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True'
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.

Sticking with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/[]"[]//g' File.csv
```

For non-GNU `sed` (such as the BSD version that ships with OS X), the `-i` (in-place) option is not available, so you have to write to a new file and then replace:

```
sed 's/[]"[]//g' File.csv >NewFile.csv && mv NewFile.csv File.csv
```

There are other commands you can use in that case; the one with the shortest command line to do this (not counting the redirection and renaming) is probably `tr`:

```
tr -d '[]"' <File.csv >NewFile.csv && mv NewFile.csv File.csv
```

Explanation of the `sed` regular expression:

Any set of characters inside `[`...`]` brackets creates a "character class" that is a shorthand for single-character alternation. That is, the meaning of `[abc]` is "`a` or `b` or `c`".  If you want to include a literal `[` or `]` inside a character class, you can do so by placing the bracket immediately next to the opposite one that encloses the character class: `[]abc]` includes `a`, `b`, `c`, and `]`, while `[abc[]` includes `a`, `b`, `c` and `[`.  So `[]"[]` includes `[`, `"`, and `]`.

Comment: Just keep in mind that `-i` is a GNU extension to `sed`, and may not be available on all systems. :)

Comment: tr doesn't take files as arguments does it ? You would have to `cat`(or something similar) into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/\("\[\)*\(]"\)*//g' File.csv > /tmp/File.csv && mv /tmp/File.csv File.csv
```

- to avoid to remove `[`, `]` or `"` inside `'content'`. (avoiding `]"` `"[` should also be done but less occurence for lot more complex sed action.
- Posix version (so `--posix` on GNU sed)